# Xamarin app for android and IOS with multi-menu

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I was trying to make an android and IOS app in Xamarin, with an SSO login system and then some other pages. The thing is, I want a menu that is accessible everywhere, screen:

[image: full_screen]

As you can see, on every single page there is a hamburger menu, is this possile, and how?

Comment: yes, use a MasterDetail page.  The detail will be your different pages, and the master will contain your menu

Comment: Okay, I'll try this out, thanks!